# Maven copy JAR generated in Target to external folder

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

In regular Netbeans project you have a build.xml where I am able to copy the generated JAR file to a different folder(s) using the following:

```
<target name ="-post-jar" > 
    <copy file ="${dist.jar}" todir ="../Plugin Jars" failonerror ="true"/> 

    <copy file ="${dist.jar}" todir ="/Users/dev/Desktop/plugins" failonerror ="true"/> 
</target>
```

Now that I have a project that uses Maven, I can't find the way to accomplish the same.

**EDIT:** Thanks to our contributors I was able to do it with the following entry

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-installed</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                  <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/dev/Desktop/plugins</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I think you can accomplish that by using copy-dependencies goal like this:  <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>

Comment: where should put the path?

Comment: This is the full code: <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>

Comment: So you have now bound your build with your local configuration of folder structure and operation system...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the maven-dependency-plugin

The following documentation has an example where they copy the just built artifact to a custom location.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html (search the page for "The dependency:copy goal can also be used to copy the just built artifact to a custom location if desired")

Comment: Thanks @Deadron I will update my post with the proper code that you suggest